# Azure Analysis Service Rest API Sync Parameters

Tags: azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to call the /Sync function on the Azure Analysis Service Rest API. The official documentation doesn't cover what information to be included in the body of the POST. Has anyone found an example of this?

Official doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh#post-sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedback from Microsoft clarified that you don't need to pass any additional information in the body of the post. The Sync command for Azure Analysis services is different from the TMSL Synchronize command. With Azure Analysis services, you need to have setup replicas for the Sync command to be useful. It will synchronize the replicas with your model.